# How do you save an image as a gif with transparency in c#?

Tags: c#, gif

I'm working on code to format images for use in a game I play.  That game uses either jpg images or gif images; if a gif is selected, any transparency is replaced in game by some context-sensitive backgrounds.  I have a large collection of images (jpg and png mostly) that I'm trying to adjust for this purpose, and it was all going swimmingly to convert to jpgs -- I easily figured out how to add the 'standard' background that the game uses to images with transparency, and save as jpg.

But when I tried to save those same images, without the background, as a gif, I found that the background was instead black.  In trying to research the issue, I found a whole bunch of articles from 4-6 years ago talking about how .NET doesn't play nice with gif transparency.  I tried a few of the solutions I found, but none of them seem to work.

The one that seemed the most promising goes through the gif-saved image a few bytes at a time looking for a transparency color and then (I think) replace all instances of that with a reference to the first one?  I don't know enough about the gif format to really follow what it's trying to do with a bunch of magic numbers.

I've tried using Color.Transparent on all the individual pixels.  I've tried using bitmap.MakeTransparent.  The images are all of PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb, which my research says is acceptable (though the one article I read suggested that 8bpp might be better, it seems that would provide a massive reduction in image quality which I'm not wanting).

Here's the code that I'm currently running with (that does not work):

```
    private void ConvertToGif(Image source, string destination, bool resize, bool includeBackground)
        {

            if (resize == true && source.Width == source.Height)
            {
                // Resize Image
                var resizedImage = ResizeImage(source);
                if (includeBackground)
                {
                    resizedImage = AddBackground(resizedImage);
                    resizedImage.Save(destination, ImageFormat.Gif);
                }
                else
                {
                    Color makeTransparent = getNonExistentColor(resizedImage);

                    resizedImage = RemoveBackground(resizedImage, makeTransparent);
                    var bitmap = new Bitmap(resizedImage);
                    resizedImage = MakeTransparentGif(bitmap, makeTransparent);
                    resizedImage.Save(destination, ImageFormat.Gif);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                source.Save(destination, ImageFormat.Gif);
                //MessageBox.Show("Unable to convert to TEW Jpg; image must be a square.");
            }

        }

private Bitmap MakeTransparentGif(Bitmap bitmap, Color color)
        {
            byte R = color.R;
            byte G = color.G;
            byte B = color.B;
            MemoryStream fin = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(fin, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            MemoryStream fout = new MemoryStream((int)fin.Length);
            int count = 0;
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            byte transparentIdx = 0;
            fin.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //header  
            count = fin.Read(buf, 0, 13);
            if ((buf[0] != 71) || (buf[1] != 73) || (buf[2] != 70)) return null; //GIF  
            fout.Write(buf, 0, 13);
            int i = 0;
            if ((buf[10] & 0x80) > 0)
            {
                i = 1 << ((buf[10] & 7) + 1) == 256 ? 256 : 0;
            }
            for (; i != 0; i--)
            {
                fin.Read(buf, 0, 3);
                if ((buf[0] == R) && (buf[1] == G) && (buf[2] == B))
                {
                    transparentIdx = (byte)(256 - i);
                }
                fout.Write(buf, 0, 3);
            }
            bool gcePresent = false;
            while (true)
            {
                fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
                fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
                if (buf[0] != 0x21) break;
                fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
                fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
                gcePresent = (buf[0] == 0xf9);
                while (true)
                {
                    fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
                    fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
                    if (buf[0] == 0) break;
                    count = buf[0];
                    if (fin.Read(buf, 0, count) != count) return null;
                    if (gcePresent)
                    {
                        if (count == 4)
                        {
                            buf[0] |= 0x01;
                            buf[3] = transparentIdx;
                        }
                    }
                    fout.Write(buf, 0, count);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0)
            {
                count = fin.Read(buf, 0, 1);
                fout.Write(buf, 0, 1);
            }
            fin.Close();
            fout.Flush();
            return new Bitmap(fout);
        }
```

Can anyone help?  Is this just a fools errand with .NET still?

Comment: I just tested MakeTransparentGif() and it works just fine for me. Perhaps you're not using it right.

Comment: Perhaps.  But I'm giving it the image and a color to make transparent.  It's saving it as a gif with the "transparent" pixels as black.  Even when I open it afterwards in GIMP, those pixels are black not transparent.  So, what do I need to do in order to 'use it right'?

Comment: Few things could be going wrong. 1. gimp doesn't support transparency. 2. The pixels are just dark, not pure black and so the masking fails. 3. Check if its transparent simply by opening the resulting image in internet explorer. The transparent should be white to match the web page background. Also save the bitmap with the .gif file name, but don't specify the gif file type constant or it may re-encode it and strip out the transparency.

Comment: Think I figured out what what is going on.  I downloaded the gif spec and stepped through that MakeTransparentGif code.  It looks like it'll only mark a color as transparent if it actually exists in the color table; it won't actually add an entry to the colortable.  Since I was just grabbing a random color that didn't exist in the image to use as transparent, that was silently failing.